# How can I change screen resolution?

Tags: 12.04, resolution, eeepc

I have a Asus EEE PC Netbook, 1015CX. I have created a bootable usb to try Ubuntu and to test how it looks.

The main problem is that the screen resolution is locked at 800x600 where as my netbook usually runs at 1024 minimum. How can I change it? I see no option in the menu.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and run: `xrandr` and add the ouput to your question?

Comment: Try **xrandr -s 1024x768**  (running xrandr without any options will give a list of supported resolutions).

Comment: Is your graphics card driver installed? This problem mostly occurs when you have the basic display driver.

Comment: I recommend expanding this to explain how to determine what driver is being used, and how to install a different one.

Answer (score 5):

Type "Displays" in the dash or click on the computer icon in the top right corner and select the second item in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Mik: tried xrandr -s 1024x600 (which this netbook runs at in Windows) and got:
"size 1024x600 not found in available modes"

Zigg: In Lubunut, 'monitor settings applet only offers 800x600

Right,just found this, which may be the solution:

[Support for Intel GMA 3600](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11976680&postcount=97)

I'll try it, when I'm feeling calm and I've had a strong cup of tea. But if anyone wants to send me an easier way to get 1024x600, shoot,

Answer (score 1):

You can even use custom resolution with this method. It really works for me.

http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the "Displays" control applet.  If X thinks you can change your resolution, you can do it here.