# Install Ubuntu too big

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, usb-installation

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a 
Thinkpad T440p.

I have gotten the point where I can install but everything
on the screen is so big that I cannot click "continue" and 
do not have another way of proceeding.

Is there a way to resize the screen?  I have tried displays 
but there are not many options I can reach.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You could try using 'Tab' to select the continue button...

Comment: The 'Tab' button does not work in the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the window by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and dragging it with your mouse (from any point, not the title bar on the top). It's not a total solution but it would help you carry on.

When you get into the display settings, if the settings indicate that you are already at the native resolution of your laptop, you should check on the `Scale for menu and title bars` setting and be sure it's set to 1. Having used that with Ubuntu 14.04 as an HTPC, it sounds like that could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the Alt key.  Once installed everything was okay with screen size.  Now I  need to figure out why it does not shut down.

Comment: glad I could help!! :D you can ask a new question about the shut down thing.

Comment: I did.  This is my next battle to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resize your display to the desired size from the command line by running `xrandr -s $WIDTHx$HEIGHT` (but substitute in your own values for `$WIDTH` and `$HEIGHT`).  `xrandr` man page is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xrandr.1.html).

There is a similar question that's already been answered here:
[How can I change screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139006/how-can-i-change-screen-resolution)

If the problem turns out to just be that your laptop has a very small display, there are some workarounds for that, too, some of which are documented here: https://superuser.com/questions/247463/netbook-screen-too-small-software-fix

I'm a particular fan of [newrez](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=134686), myself, if low native resolution turns out to be your issue.